# Just Upgraded to Mojave and started getting the Out of Application Memory box

Tags: mojave

[image]I have just migrated to Mojave and with no applications open, except whatever runs in the background, I receive the Out of Application Memory panel.  The only app it shows as running is Finder.  I am running on a Mac Mini with 815 Gbytes available on my system drive. I did not have this error before upgrading to Mojave.

Comment: how much RAM do you have ? click on the Activity monitor and report

Comment: It is a Mac Mini with 8 GB memory.  I am currently getting the error with only Finder and Activity Monitor running.  I have just started Chrome to send this message.  Activity Monitor shows App Memory at 5.13 GB right now

Comment: Wow, that is high, I have 3.5 GB but have Firefox, Chrome, Skype, Mail ect running.

Comment: take a screenshot of your Activity monitor and post here

Comment: Attached are screenshots of the Activity Monitor both CPU screen and Memory screen. (If I can figure out how to attach screenshots.)

Comment: Sorry, I don't see an option to add attachments.

Comment: no problem. Click on edit under our post here. Under the title then Body there are icons, one looks like photo. Click on it, find the photo and add.

Comment: Don't see edit in this mode, but I remember seeing it after I created a response.  So here is the response.  I am editing now but do not see the photo icon.  I did not see edit when reviewing the posts, only after I posted my response.  I am at the apple.stackexchange.com . . . selection in Google.

Comment: I am sorry, I had a typo, it meant to say Edit under Your post, not our post

Comment: OK, I finally found a way to include the images.

Comment: Get rid of MacKeeper! It's basically malware.

Comment: Thank you, nice work, Now we can see !!! and you are NOT out of memory ! So your hardware is fine. That must be a bug in Mojave, not sure which one.  Open Dropbox and set it to NO Finder Integration.

Comment: You also have a lot 3D party apps running. Some might not be Mojave compatible, so for now Just turn them all off, like MacKeeper, Presto Scan...and others.

Comment: MacKeeper is malware.

Comment: I'm getting this constantly now after upgrading to 10.14.3 two days ago.  I'm running MacOS inside VmWare Workstation, though, so I can never tell what's really going on.

Answer (score 1):

You are NOT out of memory !

That notification is false.

It shows you are using 3.1GB out of 8GB, so you have 5GB free Memory.

So your hardware is fine.

That must be a bug in Mojave, not sure which one. For some reason the Applications are reporting wrong Memory usage, even so the Activity monitor does not show that.

You also have a lot 3D party apps running. Some might not be Mojave compatible, so for now Just turn them all off, Presto Scan...and others.

It is also advised to completely remove MacKeeper, since it has been reported as Malware, and Mac OS X is perfectly safe without it.

Possible fix:

Go to Dropbox icon > Cog wheel at the bottom left > Preferences Disable "Enable Finder Integration"

Comment: I deleted MacKeeper and haven't had the issue since then.  Not sure that was the fix, but I'll go with it for now.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: If you think I helped you in some ways, please check my answer so others can find it.